# How to check if an image URL has been inputted into a Prompt - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, url, prompt

```
$(function() {
      $(".upload").click(function() {
          link = prompt("Paste a background image url");
          if (link == null) {
          return;
          }
          else {
          div = document.createElement('div');
          $(div).addClass("images").html('<img src="' + link + '">');
          $(".display").append(div);
          }
        });
    });
```

Above is the code that I am currently using which asks the user to input an Image URL of which a new div is created with the inputted image within.

If the user inputs a bit of text (or something that isn't an image URL), the div would still be created though the image tag would read:

How do I check to see if the user inputs an image URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You COULD just do:

```
 var extension = id.substr(link.length - 3); // get last 3 chars from the string
 if ((extension == "bmp") || (extension == "png") || ... you get the idea ) {
 do right stuff
 else
 do wrong stuff
```

But, you have to take into consideration before displaying the link, that it could also be trying do some XSS, so take the proper considerations

Answer (score 0):

You could check the link with a regular expression:

`(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(link)`

However, this will only check the file extension, you can still not be sure if the selected file actually exists and if it's a valid image file.

The only "safe" way would be to upload the selected file to your server and check with python/Java/PHP/... if it's actually an image file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error event when you load an image and remove it:

```
// hook the event before you create any actual images (e.g. document ready)
$(".display").on("error", "img", function() {
    alert(this.src + " is not a valid image");
});
```